# Simplest way to solve a polynomial lm

Tags: r

(I know this has been answered somewhere else but I just can't find a simple generic solution for R)

What is the simplest way to take a polynomial model, e.g.:

```
fit <- lm(y~x+I(x^2))
```

and find the minimum / maximum / turning point?

I tried the polynom package but I get an error "'a' must be a numeric matrix".

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a quadratic model y = b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2 then we know the max/min occurs at x = -b1/(2*b2).

```
b0 <- 2
b1 <- 3
b2 <- -0.5

x <- seq(0, 5, .1)
n <- length(x)
y <- b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2 + rnorm(n, 0, .5)
plot(x,y)
o <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
lines(x, predict(o))
est.max <- -coef(o)[2]/(2*coef(o)[3])
abline(v = est.max)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Dason. And to find the Y-value, what's that formula?

Comment: You have the regression equation.  Plug that x value into the equation.  Using `predict` will do this for you.